# Am I overengineering MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

On my project, I have to make difference between registered users, and simple visitors. Both of them can set their own properites, specified in `accounts` and `visitors` table.

I identify them by cookie, if there is no cookie, a user can log in, and create a session (and a "remember me" cookie if she wishes) and the simple one time visitor also creates a cookie and a session.

I split the current session to either `accountSession` (logged in person), and to `visitorSession` (simple visitor).

I insert the visited `pages`, `userAgents`, `IPs` by the `accountSession` OR the `visitorSession`.

Am I overengineering?

Here is the diagram:

[image: MySQL]

Comment: I suspect this would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: so.... another migration?

Answer (score 2):

So much of accounts and visitors is common, that it pains me to see the extra tables for sessions and cookies.  I'd rather see visitors with NULL values for the extra 3-4 columns.